# difference between connections in qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have some constructor for the class LCDRange:

```
 LCDRange::LCDRange(QWidget *parent)
     : QWidget(parent)
 {
     QLCDNumber *lcd = new QLCDNumber(2);
     lcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Filled);

     slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
     slider->setRange(0, 99);
     slider->setValue(0);

     connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
             lcd, SLOT(display(int)));
     connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
             this, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)));

     QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
     layout->addWidget(lcd);
     layout->addWidget(slider);
     setLayout(layout);
 }
```

but I can't understand the difference between these lines:

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 lcd, SLOT(display(int)));
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 this, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)));
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that we are in OO land, so we are operating on objects.

In order to connect a signal to something, those signal/slots have to be apart of an object.

Another way to think about it is you can't have a signal by itself, because a signal has to come from somewhere. Likewise, you can't have a slot all by itself it has to be attached to something.

Now, Qt allows you to connect a signal to a slot, but it also allows you to connect a *signal to a signal*, which is what is happening in the second connect line. This allows you to chain signals from one object to another, or you could think about it as *passing a signal through*.

Usually this happens when an Object or Widget has a **private** internal child that emits a signal, and the parent Object/Widget wants to emit the *same* signal to whoever is listening to it.

In the case of your example the LCDRange Widget contains a slider, which is an internal implementation detail. The user of LCDRange doesn't need to know about all the different components that make up the LCDRange (slider, lcdnumber, layout, etc), that's a basic requirement of encapsulation which is a huge advantage of OO.

However, the user of LCDRange will want to know when the value of LCDRange changes. And rather then creating a slot in LCDRange, that simply re-emits the signal valueChanged signal, you can *forward* or *passthrough* the valueChanged signal from the slider.

The following achieves the same effect of passing the signal through, however it requires much more code.

```
class LCDRange : public QWidget
{
// constructor and other methods
//...
signals:
    void valueChanged(int)
private slots:
    void sliderValueChanged(int);
// ...
};

// in the LCDRange constructor
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 this, SLOT(sliderValueChanged(int)));

// elsewhere in LCDRange's definition

void LCDRange::sliderValueChanged( int value )
{
    emit valueChanged( value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 lcd, SLOT(display(int)));
```

tells, if the value of the slider gets changed then `valueChanged` signal will be `emited` and it will be reflected in LCD view. i.e `display` slots gets called, whose implementation will be present in `QLCDNumber`

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 this, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)));
```

Qt offers, mechanism of connecting one signal to another signal, it implies if `slider` `valueChanged`signal is emited means present class `valueChanged`signal is emited.
the connected slot for `valueChanged` gets called